# how to load json from url on input field?

Tags: javascript

This tutorial page loads json from a hard-coded URL on page load: https://github.com/mdn/learning-area/blob/master/javascript/oojs/json/heroes-finished.html

How can I achieve the same but dynamically by adding an input field in the page and pasting the same url into that field and have that information be loaded onto the page on leaving focus of the input field (or clicking a button?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html:

```
<html>
   <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <input onblur="loadJson(event.target.value,'output')"/>
    <p id="output"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
const loadJson = (url,nodeId) =>{
  fetch (url)
  .then(result => result.json())
  .then(data => document.getElementById(nodeId).innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data))
}
```

try out this repl.it: https://repl.it/join/qeijjvpt-kouroshg

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use `try...catch`, otherwise your code will cause a syntax error:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let getRaw, doc, html, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
getRaw = (url, success, fail)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  x.open('GET', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success(x.responseText);
  }
  x.onerror = ()=>{
    if(fail)fail('xhr failure');
  }
  x.send();
}
doc = document; html = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
// here's where the magic happens
const test = I('test'), butt = I('butt');
butt.onclick = ()=>{
  console.clear();
  getRaw(test.value, res=>{
    try{
      const obj = JSON.parse(res);
      console.log(obj);
    }
    catch(e){
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  }, err=>{
      console.log(err);
  });
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0; font-size:0; overflow:hidden;
}
html,body,.main{
  width:100%; height:100%; background:#ccc;
}
.main{
  padding:10px; font-size:18px;
}
input{
  width:100%; height:38px; background:#fff; color:#000; font:bold 22px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;  padding:5px; border:1px solid #147; border-radius:3px;
}
#butt{
  background:linear-gradient(#1b7bbb,#147); color:#fff; border:0; margin-top:7px; border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'><input id='test' type='text' value='https://api.weather.gov/points/47.6062,-122.3321' /><input id='butt' type='button' value='test' /></div>
</body>
</html>
```